# A Cyclic Riley [dupl$ $icate]

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   [The Cyclic Riley #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFBwH.jpg) *1 answer*

Here we go, a classic Riley with a twist!

My firsts are the firsts of the days;
My middle is the middle, not lacking;
My lasts is the last of an n-term series;
And my whole is the whole of a cycle.

> **marked** as duplicate by [Community ♦](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) 1 minute ago
>   <sub>This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please [ask a new question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).</sub>

Comment: oooh what happens when you rot13( pyvpx ba gur gvgyr )!!! very interesting!

Comment: What is this? Seems really cool!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Cyclic Riley #1](https://tinyurl.com/2fcpre6)

Comment: Unless it is important to the question, may I suggest using the cyrillic "a" instead of the weird bar? i.e. `duplicаte` instead of `duplicate`. [javascript](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dIyGltCAnM/nChpLUBAVbWwUoPxHI1fz/HwA)

Comment: tried editing it, doesnt work @Hugh

Comment: Other option that might work is `dupl$ $icate`...

Comment: What is up with this duplicate mark?

Comment: @Certainlynotadog There's no duplicate mark :-)

Comment: Ah, the comments make sense now. Clever. Although I feel this may deter some people from clicking on the question.

Comment: Isn't impersonating a Moderator a crime in SE's eyes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Month

My firsts are the firsts of the days;

> **Mon**day

My middle is the middle, not lacking;

> **nt** - "not" lacking the middle letter.

My lasts is the last of an n-term series;

> **nth**

And my whole is the whole of a cycle.

> Monthly cycle.

Comment: Had the same, but decided not to post, because "lacking" didn't seem to fit in there.

Comment: @Bass I've just had a thought that it might be instead "nt", that is "not" lacking a letter, is this a better fit?

Comment: Lacking the middle letter nonetheless! @hexomino

Comment: @JMP yes, that's probably it then

Comment: Nice answer! The green check, escorted by a crew of fifteen reputable bodyguards, is searching its way to your Puzzling account. Please be patient ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are a:

> Sundial

My firsts are the firsts of the days:

> SUN - Sunday is the first day of the week.

My middle is the middle, not lacking;

> DIA - Diameter is the middle of a circle. Diameter is also a unit of linear measurement of magnification power (which is related to the not lacking part)

My lasts is the last of an n-term series;

> L - A constant l is often used to represent the last number in a n-term series.

And my whole is the whole of a cycle:

> A sundial can measure seasonal cycles/time.

Comment: why... this sounds so plausible, yet it's not the intended answer. sorry and keep it up!